# Access vertex via ID given by VERTEXID semantic in NVIDIA's CG?

Tags: opengl, shader, cg

is there a way to access the actual vertex-data with its VERTEXID?

You can access it in CG inside the geometry shader like this:

```
AttribArray<int> vertexID : VERTEXID
```

My idea was to store the ID of a vertex as an attribute of another
vertex and reuse it in the next render-pass. But Nvidias documentation only
enlightens me about how to GET the ID, not how to access something with it.

Referenced documentation: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/gp4gp.html

Comment: Isn't Cg dead and buried yet?

Comment: You can do programmable vertex pulling a number of ways, but none of them will resemble anything from Cg. In truth, the purpose of exposing `vertex id` is not to let you fetch an arbitrary vertex, but for a handful of algorithms that benefit from knowing what vertex they are working on. It's more relevant in geometry shaders than vertex. I doubt you can do anything useful with it in Cg.

Comment: Scratch parts of that last comment -- Cg was extended for Geometry and Tessellation. I agree whole heatedly with Nicol on this though, and have to ask -- _why?!_

Comment: I am currently working on a GPU-sided mesh-deformation in Ogre3D. Sadly, I have not managed to get even a simple GLSL shader to work with Ogre's RenderToVertex-implemenation. I even tried to run the given sample-project with only glsl-shaders. Didn't work. And because I can't use HLSL (render-system has to be OpenGL), I'm kinda forced to use CG :(

Comment: I've no idea how Ogre's render to vertex buffer stuff works, but since pulling vertices the way you want really isn't possible the only thing that makes sense is if you get a stream of vertex indices from the GPU and use those as an element array buffer (using GL buffer object commands to manage the memory). That's effectively what you are already trying to do, only this doesn't require any special shading language stuff.